# ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #6 has length 1; 2 is required

Tags: python

I have some Python code meant to take some data and recreate a string from that data, but I'm receiving an error.

```
def remove_cruft(s):
     return s[1:-2]

import re

filetouse = input("What file would you like to use?\n>>>")
filetouse = filetouse + ".txt"
f = open(filetouse,"r")
lines = f.readlines()
indexlist = lines[2]
indexdict = lines[1]

indexdict = indexdict.split()
indexdict.remove("['")
indexdict.remove("']") 
for item in indexdict:
    if "'," in indexdict:
        indexdict.remove("',")
    if "'" in indexdict:
        indexdict.remove("'")
    if '",' in indexdict:
        indexdict.remove('",')
    if '"' in indexdict:
        indexdict.remove('"')

indexdict = str(indexdict)
indexdict = indexdict[1:-1]
indexdict.replace(" ", "")

dict(x.split('=') for x in indexdict.split(','))

print(indexlist)
print(indexdict)
newindexlist = remove_cruft(indexlist)
newindexlist = re.findall(r"[\w']+|[.,!?;]", newindexlist)
del newindexlist[1::2]
print(newindexlist)

posindexdict = 0
finaloutput = []

print(finaloutput)
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\IOTA\ControlledAssessment\assess87\My Documents\Python\Task 3\Decompression v1.3.py", line 31, in <module>
    dict(x.split('=') for x in indexdict.split(','))
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #6 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Comment: Looks like element number 6 didn't have an `=` in it.

Comment: The list with elements in it is:

'this=0', 'is=1', 'a=2', 'simple=3', 'test=4', 'file=5', ',=6', 'im=7', 'just=8', 'using=9', 'it=10', 'to=11', 'my=13', 'code=14', '.=15', 'i=16', 'hope=17', 'that=18', "it'll=19", 'work=20', 'with=21', 'more=22', 'than=23', 'one=24', 'line=25', 'because=26', 'other=27', 'wise=28', ';=29', 'be=31', 'very=32', 'diffcult=33', '!=37'

Comment: Hang on; why are you manually parsing the string representation of a `list` (`indexdict`) instead of using `ast.literal_eval()`? Please print `lines[2]` and `lines[1]` and edit them into your question.

Comment: Wait, you manually parse a string representation of a `list`, and then _you send it to `str()` again_? That is a sure way to cause yourself all sorts of headaches.

Answer (score 0):

One of the parameter options for [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) is an iterable of iterables of which each has exactly two objects:

```
>>> dict((('a', 1), ('b', 1)))
{'a': 1, 'b': 1}
```

Your code is trying to pass in an iterable where one of the sub iterables has only one object:

```
>>> dict((('a', 1), ('b')))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #1 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Based on the output it seems that 7th element in your data is not in the format you expect.

Comment: How can we resolve this? I mean give some default value to it? As we can not change the input.